# using Relations in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have two collections namely Employees and Departments. In that i gave reference to the employee collection's department_id field from department using has_many and belongs_to

```
class Employee
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :name, type: String
   field :age, type: Integer
   field :empid, type: String
   field :manager_id, type: Integer
   field :department_id, type:Integer
   attr_accessible :age, :empid,  :name, :department_id, :manager_id
   validates_presence_of :name
   validates_uniqueness_of :empid
   belongs_to :department
end

class Department
  include Mongoid::Document
    field :name, type: String
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :employees
end
```

now i want to refer the _id of department collection using employees, help me

Answer (score 4):

This question is inherently flawed, from the title itself.  You may be aware, but Mongo is not a relational database and therefore you should avoid using it for highly relational data models.

Mongo has no notion of a JOIN query, so simple relations are much more expensive to query than they would be in a SQL database.

The traditional way of managing this relation would be to keep a List of id's on one side of the relation.   If you will more often ask "What employees belong to department x?" then keep a List of employee_ids on each Department object.   You can then look up by id.   If you will more often ask "To which Department does employee y belong?", then all you have to do is store a department_id on each Employee object and then query the Department database for it.

If you never have to work with Employees outside of Departmental context, you may want to consider embedding a list of full employee documents in the Department object.

I'm not familiar with Mongo for Rails, so I can't give you specific code examples.

Comment: Mongo is not a relational DB but it is not *Against* relations.  They key is to try and 'nest' relations [e.g. department class has all teachers as sub objects] or to do the joins in code, not in the DB.  At least AFAIK.  More info:  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design  With that noted, I'll +1 this :)

Comment: You're right, but for people starting out in mongo it's best to get them to forget the relational model and work in a Document oriented fashion, then when they absolutely need a relation they can do it the right way.